# Specific maps from singular matrices to nonsingular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a real, square matrix which is singular, and call the entries $a_{i j}$. Let $f$ be a real valued function and consider the matrix $A^f$ whose entries are $f(a_{i j})$. Are there any functions $f$ such that $A^f$ is not singular, even though $A$ is? If so, what kind of properties would the function have?

EDIT: Let me ask that $f$ be continuous, and I'm not looking for a function which can make any singular $A$ into a nonsingular $A^f$ (I assume this is not possible?). What are examples of specific pairs of singular $A$, continuous $f$, yielding nonsingular $A^f$?

Comment: Are there stipulations on $f$?

Comment: If $A = [0]$ is the $1\times 1$ singular matrix, any $f$ which sends $0$ to something else works.

Comment: Sorry, let me add some constraints to the problem. It just occurred to me that the space of possible matrices and functions are too large

Comment: The function $A \mapsto I$ (the constant map sending every matrix to the identity) is certainly continuous, and has the property that singular $A$ map to nonsingular matrices.

Comment: @DrewBrady the map I'm interested in is $A \mapsto A^f$ and vary by the choice of real-valued function $f$

Comment: My guess is that almost every continuous function has this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \left(\begin{array}{ss} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$ and $f(x) = x+1$, then $A^f = \left(\begin{array}{ss} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{array}\right)$ is non-singular.